# Unity 2D Top Down game camera jittering problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my camera movement code.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 desiredPosition = targetTransform.position + offset;
    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, desiredPosition, ref velocity,smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
    //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(targetTransform.position.x,targetTransform.position.y,-10), 5);
}
```

...and my players movement code, it's called by playerscript's `FixedUpdate()`:

```
private void move()
{
    rb.velocity = -transform.up * speed*Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).position.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
            rotationTimeRight += Time.deltaTime;
            if (rotationTimeRight>0.5f)
            {
                rotationTimeRight = 0;
                Destroy(Instantiate(rotationTraceRight, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.3f, transform.position.z), rotationTraceRight.transform.rotation),5.0f);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
            rotationTimeLeft += Time.deltaTime;
            if (rotationTimeLeft > 0.5f)
            {
                rotationTimeLeft = 0;
                Destroy(Instantiate(rotationTraceLeft, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.3f, transform.position.z), rotationTraceLeft.transform.rotation),5.0f);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rotationTimeRight = 0;
        rotationTimeLeft = 0;
    }
}
```

Camera perfectly follow player and have zero jitter on player sprite.The problem is when look at other objects in scene there is an annoying jitter problem on other sprites.I tried smoothdamp,lerp everything but its does not fix.

Comment: @MickyD in playerscripts fixedupdate

Comment: Have you tried moving your camera movement into `LateUpdate`?

Comment: @derHugo i tried it but its give huge jittering on player sprite.